# DoubleRenderError but only one render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this

```
class ScriptsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def run
    @script.update(script_params)
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ScriptRunnerJob.new(@script)
    render head :ok
  end
end
```

I get a DoubleRenderError in run.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`render` and `head` are both methods that perform a render; you only want to call one of them.

```
# This is all you need
head :ok
```